# Diagonalisibility of a certain matrix $A_{\sigma}$ induced by a permutation $\sigma$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of the set $\{ 1, 2, \cdots, n\}$. Consider the $n \times n$ matrix $A_{\sigma}$ whose $ith$ row is the standard vector $e_{\sigma(i)}$.

With this setting I am looking for the answer of the following questions :

For which $\sigma$ , $A_{\sigma}$ is diagonalisable over

1) $\mathbb{C}$

2) $\mathbb{R}$

Thank you in advance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The matrix is orthogonal/unitary. Isn't it?

Comment: Each $A_\sigma$ is an orthogonal matrix. So (1) always holds. In particular they are normal. A normal matrix has real spectrum if and only if it is selfadjoint (here, symmetric). Thus, (2) holds if and only if $A_\sigma$ is symmetric. Now, find the corresponding $\sigma$'s.